# XML Output in PHP (UTF-8)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, utf-8

I'm following this tutorial to implement google maps into my webpage:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#createtable

Everything went perfect with my Data Base connection. The information in my Data Base has characters like "á,é,í"

When I try to check the XML file in the browser it has this error:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 10: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

On the map the data is shown as: Bogot�. Capital de Colombia.
instead of: Bogotá.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164719/utf-8-encoding-xml-in-php

Comment: Show us, how you connect to the database and retrieve the data.

Comment: `header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");` for frontend output

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. I already tried header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); and still not working.

Comment: I used this function  utf8_encode, and it works, Thanks

Comment: We need to see how you connect to the database.  And what SQL commands were used to insert/select that data.  You probably had something defaulting to `CHARACTER SET latin1` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: use `utf8_encode utf8_decode` on the xml file maybe that helps like `echo utf8_decode(file_get_contents(path));` and DB maybe GOOGLE: MYSQL SET NAMES

Comment: But you have to go more into ENCODING Topic:db connection,ouput encoding, xml encoding ... and how there work together

Comment: Thanks, It is working now:   echo 'datos="' . utf8_encode($row['datos']) . '" ';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything went perfect with my Data Base connection. The information in my Data Base has characters like "á,é,í"

Please note the little details here:

On the one hand you write

> Everything went perfect with my Data Base connection.

And on the other you write:

> The information in my Data Base has characters like "á,é,í"

So what I'm trying to make visible here is that the database *connection* is not the database:

```
[PHP code] <--- database connection ---> [database server]-+-[data]
```

The database connection is the negotiation of the data-flow between the server and your program.

Encoding is meta-information and where-ever you pass the data (strings) along, this meta-information about the encoding is either right or wrong.

When it's wrong this can lead to unexpected results. Results like you experience it:

> Bogot�. Capital de Colombia.

(instead of *"Bogotá.  Capital de Colombia."*)

From experience I can tell you the following about this bigger picture:

1. That the browser gives you the � character is a sign that it caught a binary-sequence of data that can't make a valid code-point (let's say a Letter here in short) out of it and display that letter nicely. Instead it displays the question mark in the diamond to signal a problem.
2. This is a sign that Unicode encoding was expected and not given.
3. From experience you're feeding a single-byte character set as UTF-8.

There can be multiple reasons for that.

So let's remember what I just wrote above about the meta-data next to the data itself and review the database-connection:

```
[PHP code] <--- database connection ---> [database server]-+-[data]
```

And most of all the good news: The database connection allows you as the programmer of the PHP code tell the database which encoding you expect.

The database server then looks into the data it has when you request data from it and it will encode the data in the encoding you asked for it. Isn't that nice?

So all you need to do is to tell the database server which character encoding you expect.

For that you need to know which character encoding you will serve the response with. This is most often UTF-8 in the web nowadays. So tell your database server you want UTF-8. And all should be fine:

- [PHP PDO: charset, set names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361459/367456) (Reference Question on Stackoverflow)

Edit: And seeing your comments: No, you added the `utf8_encode` calls in there needlessly. The database can give you the data correctly encoded already (and always correct). `utf8_encode` is *only* working for Latin-1 encoded strings, it will fail when you have data differently from within the database. Don't make this too specific, instead just use the correct parameters for the database connection and you've got far less things to worry about because you know which encoding you've asked for.

Important principle: Whenever possible, ask for the things you want instead of creating them your own.