# How to create a Rest server in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I'm going to create a Restful web service API using PHP. I've googled and found how to create a rest client, but I want to know how to create rest server instead.

I already have a MySQL database to retrieve the data but I don't know how to output my results in XML format.

Comment: So your question is just with writing an XML file? If you're not dependent on XML you may also simply use JSON, which requires only one call to `json_encode`.

Comment: Unless you specifically need XML, I would recommend using JSON as an output format, because it's much easier to deal with on the client side.

Comment: the XML output, i will use in android device too. can json be used on android device? if it can, how can i create that? please give me some advice:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to generate xml file dynamically using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api), which is an extensible PHP script that I wrote that does exactly what you want: provide a REST API based on a MySQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a framework like [FRAPI](http://getfrapi.com) that helps you build REST services with minimum effort.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RockWall engine. The main feature of RockWall is multiple REST requests by single HTTP request.

[RockWall REST engine site](https://rockwall.github.io/RockWall.PHP/)