# currency convert function based on URL $_GET variables

Tags: php, rest, get

I want to take the values from the URL and perform a currency conversion based on them. EG-

I want to receive URL's as:

http://www.mysite.com/conv/?amnt=7.15&from=GBP&to=USD

The returned results will then be in XML format.

My question is - how can I read those values, check for particular errors, perform the convert function and finally output the XML response using a RESTful interface?

Obviously, I'm not looking for the code to be written for me, I just need the logic explained to me and how can I can go about building this (I'm very new to this so forgive the vagueness)

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? That might help when looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and many questions I've nearly finished building this :)

Here's how I did it in pseudo-code:

```
1) URL is called
    - Check for request type (get/put etc)
    - Add the get values to PHP variables
    - Check for errors in the GET call (if error, load error from our pre-defined errors file and build XML page + change content type)
    - If all is good - load the currency converson function
2) Call conversion function
    - Load currency rates from XML file in Cache
    - Check currency timestamp (If older than 2 hours, re-import from web with fallback options).
    - Perform conversion using the available variables
    - Build XML response and output to page.
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn about:

- [$_GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)
- [dynamically generateing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)
- [PHP arithmetic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)
- [PHP and REST](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)