# PHP to MySQL to XML file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, xml

I am trying to create a php web form that saves data to a MySQL database, and as soon as the data is saved to the database a xml file is generated.  I have the code to save the data to the database and I can create a xml from the data, I just can't do it all at once.

I was thinking I could use a javascript redirect to kick off the .php file to create my xml file, but that's where I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent functions, classes and external libraries for that, just have a look on that http://css.dzone.com/news/creating-xml-documents-php and [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)