# Wordpress XML generate Help Needed

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Hello can anyone help me, i need to generate  custom xml file from wordpress recent posts how can i do this ? i need to use in tiles of windows 8. How can i generate xml file using wordpress please ? format i m looking to generate is

```
<tile>
  <visual>
    <binding template="TileWideText09">
       <text id="1">wordpress auto title here</text>
       <text id="2">wordpress auto description here</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```

i dont know how to do that please help me in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to query Wordpress for the posts you want to use, for example using [`wp_query()`.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) (if you are used to using The Loop) or using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)  (The more "programmery" way).

With the resulting data, then build an XML output as outlined in 
[How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/486757)