# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element - PHP

Tags: php, html, css, xml, xml-parsing

I was dynamically creating XML File in PHP.  I was taking hints from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php).  I was trying the first answer for that question.  Obviously it was working good and not working certain circumstances.  I was dynamically passing the arrays into that xml file.  The field Description contains some special characters i think so and i was getting the error "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element".  I was trying various possibilities. One such is the following which will make escape from the special characters.

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'   
            'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>";
```

But it doesn't works for me well.  Kindly give me some suggestion how to solve this case.

Comment: Check if you have any unwanted characters after ?> tag

Comment: Sorry nothing is there after ?>