# Making html-xml tree with php

Tags: php, xml

Can you please tell me how this thing is called or maybe you can tell me how to make one. I have a mysql database with some rows, for example name, surname. I need to know how to pass those values to a document like this:

```
<Product>
  <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
  <Discontinued>false</Discontinued>
  <ProductID>1</ProductID>
  <ProductName>Chai</ProductName>
  <QuantityPerUnit>10 boxes x 20 bags</QuantityPerUnit>
  <ReorderLevel>10</ReorderLevel>
  <SupplierID>1</SupplierID>
  <UnitPrice>18.00</UnitPrice>
  <UnitsInStock>39</UnitsInStock>
  <UnitsOnOrder>0</UnitsOnOrder>
</Product>
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/486757/367456)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably the simpliest way is using [PHP's *SimpleXML* module](http://php.net/simplexml).

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleXML in PHP to easily create an XML file: http://php.net/simplexml