# Multiple markers on google maps using PHP arrays with data from Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, google-maps

So my first post on stack overflow,
I have 2 PHP arrays that contains latitude and longitude. The values that these variables store depends on what the user searches for.

I have a simple map that i got from the google maps api tutorial, How can i add multiple markers to the map using only latitude and longitude from php arrays?

I am very grateful for any kind response to this

```
 <head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="searchnext.css"/>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(57.708742,11.820850),
  zoom:10,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
  <body>



<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

 <?php

include_once'config/connect.php';
$search= $_POST['search'];
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$search = stripslashes($search);

$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

$sql= "select * from venue where vID in (select vID from sv where sID in (select sID from sports where sN = '$search'));";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$latitude = array();
$longitude = array();

while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($latitude, $row1['latitude']);

}
while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($longitude, $row2['longitude']);

}

echo $latitude[1];
echo $latitude[2];
echo $latitude[3];
?>
</body>
```

Comment: If you used the Google Maps store locator tutorial that I think you did, then the tutorial itself shows you how to add markers to the map!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an XML document of markers which is generated by PHP.

You can have a look at the format of the XML document here:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/

So all you will need to do is create an XML file using your PHP data like this one:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/data.xml

You can read about how to do that here:

[How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)

And then use this code to display the markers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  downloadUrl("data.xml", function(data) {
    var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have a problem with the maps code, i can't get maps to show up at all with the code u sent, where did you get the code from? thanks

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/downloadurl.html, if you grab the source from there you should be able to get it working.