# create and adding info to XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to create PHP page that allow me to add data into the XML file,
I want to make the xml file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfPlayer>
  <Player>
    <DisplayName>FuznesS</DisplayName>
    <UserID>123123</UserID>
  </Player>
   <Player>
    <DisplayName>Vortex</DisplayName>
    <UserID>321321</UserID>
  </Player>
</ArrayOfPlayer>
```

and be able to add more

```
<Player>
    <DisplayName>Vortex</DisplayName>
    <UserID>321321</UserID>
</Player>
```

and everyting that I adding will be inside the

```
<ArrayOfPlayer>

</ArrayOfPlayer>
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php?rq=1

Comment: I already checked it, but its not adding what I want inside <ArrayOfPlayer> </ArrayOfPlayer>. its just making everytime a new <ArrayOfPlayer> for each <Player>

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: I did, but there is a error, I have post the error in the comment of your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, just replace the variables:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<ArrayOfPlayer/>');

foreach ($players AS $player) {
    $track = $xml->addChild('Player');
    $track->addChild('DisplayName', $display_name);
    $track->addChild('UserID', $user_id);
 }

 Header('Content-type: text/xml');
 print($xml->asXML());
```

*** EDIT ***

Well, here's my revised answer, hope this will help:

```
<?php
$filename = 'file.xml';
$new_displayname = 'Vortex';
$new_userid = '321321';


$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->load($filename);
$root=$doc->documentElement;

$arrayofplayer = $doc->getElementsByTagName("ArrayOfPlayer");

$arrayofplayer = $doc->createElement('Player');
$arrayofplayer = $root->appendChild($arrayofplayer);

$player = $doc->createElement('DisplayName');
$player = $arrayofplayer->appendChild($player);
$displayname = $doc->createTextNode($new_displayname);
$displayname = $player->appendChild($displayname);

$player = $doc->createElement('UserID');
$player = $arrayofplayer->appendChild($player);
$userid = $doc->createTextNode($new_userid);
$userid = $player->appendChild($userid);

$doc->save($filename);
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS), expecting ';' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 6 ; LINE 6 for ($players AS $player) {

Comment: `for ($players AS $player) {` should be `foreach ($players as $player) {`

Comment: now its giving me the following error ; This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: I think the code was meant as a starter - you can use the loop if you want to add multiple users. Remove the foreach line and the closing bracket. Remember that you'll still need to set values for `$display_name` and `$user_id`

Comment: Yes, it's a starter. Create an array of players (either from a database or manually) or loop them.

Comment: I already set values, and when I'm doing the thing that you saying, its not saving the file, and overwrite the existing data, and I'm new with php, and especially with XML, I tried to make it work all yesterday night, and just failed.

Comment: How did you set the values?

Comment: I made index page with forms I entered the username and userID there and action takes it to test.php *the code you gave me* and then its suppose the enter the data into the xml file. but for me its just overwrite the exist data or making everytime a new <ArrayOfPlayer> for each <Player>.

Comment: ah, I see... and the xml file needs to be static then and updated with the values from the form? Is that what you want it to do?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: Please see my revised answer...

Comment: Thank you very much Wietse, you helped me alot, I'll check it more few minutes.

Comment: Its making this error now ; Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 15 ; line 15 - $arrayofplayer = $root->appendChild($arrayofplayer);

Comment: What PHP version are you using? You need PHP5 for this...

Comment: I'm using the newest version of wampserver, its PHP 5.4

Comment: there is any solution for this problem?

Comment: I saved your xml file as file.xml, then saved my php-script as index.php, and pointed my browser there. And this works for me!

Comment: Thank you very much, its working perfectly, I just forget the xml file empty, so its made this error, but now everything working great. Thank you very much :).