# I'm looking to send information from my PHP script to the client using AJAX. What is the optimal transmission form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, json

I have five separate, although related, strings of text which I need to transfer from the server (PHP) to the client (JS). I intend to use AJAX, but I've only ever used AJAX for transmitting a single line of plain text.

So, I'm wondering what options I should explore, XML, JSON, etc. in order to best transfer the information, and how to prepare/receive the information.

Comment: Depends on your data. This is a gigantically broad and opinionated question for this site.

Comment: You want to send multiple data strings?

Comment: Yes, five strings organized in some sort of structure.

Comment: Very little info. Are these strings key value pairs? What significance are they? What aspect of the application do they contribute to?

Comment: They are not key value pairs, and they are fairly significant to the application functioning, however they are also not long.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy in PHP to convert data types over to JSON, via [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode).

XML is only slightly more cumbersome, in that you have to [generate the DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php) yourself.

There is a breakdown of the pros/cons here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json