# php- How to send $_POST data to xml?

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file that contains:

```
<?php
$no = $_POST['no'];
$url = "http://domain.tld/answer.xml";
?>
```

The $url stores a URL that links to an xml file and that xml files is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1" > 
<Call> </Call>
</vxml>
```

I want to pass the $_POST['no'] to my xml file. Suppose if $_POST['no'] is 9999988888, then the  tag in xml should be like:

```
<Call>9999988888</Call>
```

Can anyone tell how to do this? :)

that xml file is on my own server.

Comment: nothing, i'm confused how to do that so i'm asking for help

Comment: Try PHP's `curl` library.

Comment: Any example pls? @Nadh

Comment: Are you trying to save the value to an XML file on the same saver or do you try to send it to a static XML file on another server? You can not modify files on another HTTP Server, you always have to call a script that saves the data to the file.

Comment: @ThW the xml file is on my own server

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/487629/2265374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), as:

```
$no = $_POST['no'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file('your_xml_file.xml');
$xml->Call = $no; 
//save/update your xml
$xml->asXML('your_xml_file.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the xml using PHP.

First of all, rename your .xml to .php.

Then, start it using

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?>
```

When you reach your call tag, change it to :

```
<Call><?php echo intval($_GET['no']); ?></Call>
```

*Note: I've assumed your `no` is a number. If it's not, remove `intval`. It's nice to have it as it will protect you from injections.*

At last, call your XML file using :

```
 $url = "http://domain.tld/answer.php?no=8877454";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should have some keywords, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1" > 
<Call>{{CALL}}</Call>
</vxml>
```

In your PHP File, just fetch this XML & use str_replace to replace those keywords,

```
<?php
$no = $_POST['no'];
$url = "http://domain.tld/answer.xml";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$newXML = str_replace("{{CALL}}", $no, $xml);
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $newXML;
?>
```