# solution search engine website php

Tags: php, file, search, web

I have website and I need to build fast search engine for it. I have to search text in database or files (word, pdf) . I want too when I search a text the result the exact word or a text which have close writing, for example, I type "exemple" the result show "example" or "examples" even if this text is in database or in files(word, pdf). My website is in PHP and I don't work with any framework. 
Can someone tell me a solution or give me a link tutorial about this.
Thanks

Comment: Also look at http://sphinxsearch.com/ which is well supported by PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php)

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking for more information about sphinxsearch and lucene and I shall see the solution which corresponds the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of solutions (e.g. do you want to index your files periodically of do you prefer ad hoc searches?).
Look up [XML parsing](https://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and [PDF parsing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8038/A-PDF-Forms-Parser).

Comment: As I'm beginner I don't know what is the best solution, is to index files or ad hoc search

Comment: if you want it fast (as per your question) you'll most likely want to index files

Comment: I see after searching information that Sphinxsearch can't index directly so I have to import the contents into XML format, can you recomment a method do this

Comment: There's a question that perfectly suites your answer! See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php.