# save data to xml file

Tags: php, codeigniter, fusioncharts

I am generating charts using fusioncharts. Using xml file to generate charts.But not able to generate xml file.

```
$colone ="";

$open_vals = "<chart  caption='Referrals' labelDisplay='Rotate' showBorder='0' showLegend ='1' showPlotBorder='0' bgColor = '#FFFFFF' plotGradientColor='#274F95' canvasBorderThickness ='0' canvasBorderColor = '#FFFFFF' numberPrefix='' formatNumberScale='0' exportEnabled='1' exportAction='Save' exportAtClient='0'>";

    $colone .= "<set label='" . $readmit_values['label'] . "' value='" .$readmit_values['value']. "' color='#274F95' />";
        $close_vals ="</chart>";
        $xml_file_content = $open_vals.$colone.$close_vals;
        $pick_time = time();
        $file_name = 'dashboard_'.$pick_time;
        $store_path = '/dashboard'.'/'.$file_name.'.xml';

        write_file($store_path, $xml_file_content);
```

Comment: Maybe the php script doesn't have the rights to create the xml file

Comment: How do i solve it?

Comment: for start, you can set the permissions of the folder to which you are trying to write. Try setting the permissions to 777 (On linux, the command is : **chmod 777 the_folder_here**). Just to test it out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php use this .