# Construct an xml file from a php array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, loops, for-loop

Inside a `for` loop I have the following code which pushes an array that contains some data inside another array:

```
$finCombo = array("color" => $color, "size" => $size, "productID" => $theProductID."-".$color, "imageURL" => 'https://click-tshirt.gr/images/detailed/all/'.$theProductCode."_".strtolower($color).'.jpg', "productURL" => $theProductURL, "title" => $theProductName, "price" => $theProductPrice, "category_path" => $theCategoryName, "availability" => $theProductAvailability, "brand" => $theProductBrand, "SKU" => $theProductCode."-".$color);

array_push($finalCmb, $finCombo);
```

The goal is to create an XML file using the data from the array. The code should return an xml file that looks like the below example:

```
<store>
    <date>2017-09-22 19:30</date>
    <products>
         <product>
             <SKU>10206-BLACK</SKU>
             <productID>338-BLACK</productID>
             <size>Small, Medium, Large, X Large</size>
             <color>BLACK</color>
             <title>Women's Jersey Short Sleeve Deep V-Neck Tee BLACK</title>
             <productURL>https://click-tshirt.gr/el-4/t-shirt-el/womens-jersey-short-sleeve-deep-v-neck-tee/</productURL>
             <imageURL>https://click-tshirt.gr/images/detailed/all/10206_Black.jpg</imageURL>
             <price>9.90</price>
             <category_path>ΓΥΝΑΙΚΕΙΑ///T-SHIRT</category_path>
             <brand>BELLA&CANVAS</brand>
             <availability>Κατόπιν παραγγελίας</availability>
         </product>
```

Here an example of the array where you can see that "425-DEEP_NAVY" is inserted in the array with the size "Medium" but later on it is inserted again and again for each size:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [color] => BLACK_DARK_GREY [size] => Small [productID] => 390-BLACK_DARK_GREY [imageURL] => https://click-tshirt.gr/images/detailed/all/18608_black_dark‌​_grey.jpg [productURL] => http://click-tshirt.gr/el-3/category-50/adult-fashion-basic-‌​ls-hooded-tee/ [title] => Adult Fashion Basic LS Hooded Tee [price] => 13.800000 [category_path] => ΑΝΔΡΙΚΑ/ΦΟΥΤΕΡΑΚΙΑ ΜΕ ΚΟΥΚΟΥΛΑ [availability] => Κατόπιν παραγγελίας [brand] => ANVIL [SKU] => 18608-BLACK_DARK_GREY )))
```

There is also one thing that happens and so far I have managed to resolve it with JavaScript. That is the products are inserted in the array for every "productID" there is several "size's" so for each size the same productID is inserted several times while what I need is that for each productID the size to be an array containing all sizes that correspond to that productID. See codepen console below:

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/miljkovicmisa/pen/RLPOGV?editors=0012)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)

Comment: Ok, it seems that your problem is not creating an XML file, but rather that you get multiple values in your array. Please post your code, so we can see what your error is. Also, don't ask two questions in the same question. Create a new question for your second part.

Comment: Checkout your `$color` variable. It is an array not a string.

Comment: Checkout your `$color` variable. It is an array not a string. In other words to get an XML like descriped you should have an array of products its elements are associative array for each product and that associative array should not has arrays as values. i.e `[0 => ['SKU' => '10206 red', 'productID' => '288-red','size' => 'small, large'],1=>[],...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Combining arrays

First, your problem probably lies in your usage of array_push.

```
$array = ['test'];
$secondarray = ['foo', 'bar'];

array_push($array, $secondarray);
```

will give you an `$array` containing the array `$secondarray`

```
Array (
    0 => (string) "test"
    1 => Array (
        0 => (string) "foo"
        1 => (string) "bar"
    )
)
```

What I guess you want is [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge), which will merge the two arrays instead.

```
$array = ['test'];
$secondArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
$resultArray = array_merge($array, $secondArray);
```

Which will give you the `$resultArray`:

```
Array(
    [1] => (string) "test"
    [2] => (string) "foo"
    [3] => (string) "bar"
)
```

### Converting to XML

You can do this in multiple ways. Write your own solution using [XmlWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) or create a DOM structure using either [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

### SimpleXml

Perhaps the simplest solution is to use [SimpleXmlElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) like this:

```
$xml = SimpleXmlElement('<store/>');
$xml->addChild('date', '2017-09-22 19:30');
$products = $xml->addChild('products');
$product  = $products->addChild('product');
foreach ($finCombo as $name => $value) {
    $product->addChild($name, $value);
}
echo $xml->asXML(), PHP_EOL;
```

### SimpleXml with Formatting

If you want to use the same formatting/indentation as in your example, you need to use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [XmlWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php). If you are already doing this in SimpleXml, you can easily load a DomDocument from a SimpleXmlElement.

```
...
$domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$domxml->formatOutput = true;
$domxml->dom_import_simplexml($xml); // load the SimpleXmlElement previously created.
echo $domxml->saveXML();
```

### DomDocument

Or you could do this directly with DOMDocument.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$store = $dom->createElement('store');
$dom->appendChild($store);
$store->appendChild($dom->createElement('date', '2017-09-22 19:30'));
$products = $dom->createElement('products');
$product = $dom->createElement('product');
foreach ($finCombo as $key => $val) {
    $product->appendChild($dom->createElement($key, $val));
}
$products->appendChild($product);
$store->appendChild($products);
echo $dom->saveXML(), PHP_EOL;
```

### XmlWriter

Or, if you want more control (e.g. over indentation), you can use [XmlWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php)

```
$writer => new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
$writer->setIndent(true);
$writer->setIndentString('    ');
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$writer->startElement('store');
$writer->startElement('date');
$writer->text('2017-09-22 19:30');
$writer->fullEndElement(); // end date element
$writer->startElement('products');
$writer->startElement('product');
foreach ($finCombo as $key => $val) {
    $writer->startElement($key);
    $writer->text($val);
    $writer->fullEndElement(); // end $key element
}
$writer->fullEndElement(); // end product element
$writer->fullEndElement(); // end products element
$writer->fullEndElement(); // end store element
$writer->endDocument();
echo $writer->flush(true);
```

Comment: Rather than converting to a string and back with `$domxml->loadXML($xml->asXML());`, you should use [`dom_import_simplexml`](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml) which directly re-wraps the object in memory (the two APIs work on the same underlying structures). I've checked, and this still lets you set the pretty-print flags on the document: https://3v4l.org/WtPsI

Comment: Great comment, I will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: okay, so here's what we get with the DOMDocument solution:


`Warning: DOMDocument::createElement() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_content\index.php on line 203

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_content\index.php:203 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\get_content\index.php(203): DOMNode->appendChild(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_content\index.php on line 203`

Comment: here is what print_r shows for the array that I need to convert to xml (this is the first entry):
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [color] => BLACK_DARK_GREY [size] => Small [productID] => 390-BLACK_DARK_GREY [imageURL] => https://click-tshirt.gr/images/detailed/all/18608_black_dark_grey.jpg [productURL] => http://click-tshirt.gr/el-3/category-50/adult-fashion-basic-ls-hooded-tee/ [title] => Adult Fashion Basic LS Hooded Tee [price] => 13.800000 [category_path] => ΑΝΔΡΙΚΑ/ΦΟΥΤΕΡΑΚΙΑ ΜΕ ΚΟΥΚΟΥΛΑ [availability] => Κατόπιν παραγγελίας [brand] => ANVIL [SKU] => 18608-BLACK_DARK_GREY )))`

Comment: @MilošMiljković, I see your problem now. Your array is an array of arrays. This is probably due to your use of `array_push()`, which pushes the variable/object you are passing it onto the array you specify. If you try to push an array onto another array, you will simply get an array containing an array. What I guess you want to do is use array_merge (http://php.net/array_merge)

Comment: @MilošMiljković, I updated my answer with code examples on array_merge vs array_push (plus a bonus section on XmlWriter). Please give it a shot and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: This works great, actually the part with the array merging is not necessary because there is an iteration going on for each product and it stores each products info in array so I do the pushing to escape the loop, anyway, what should I do about the other question? I need to loop through the array to find all the products with the same "productID" and merge their "size" in array.

Comment: @AronCederholm I have posted another question regarding the array issue. You may find it in the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775864/find-all-items-with-the-same-key-in-array-and-combine-them-in-a-new-one