# Find all items with the same key in array and combine them in a new one

Tags: php, arrays, loops, associative-array

Let's suppose we have a multidimensional array like below:

```
$obj = array
(
array("carName"=>"Volvo","carColor"=>"Red", "carSpeed"=> "100 mph"),
array("carName"=>"Volvo","carColor"=>"Blue", "carSpeed"=> "100 mph"),
array("carName"=>"BMW","carColor"=>"White", "carSpeed"=> "120 mph"),
array("carName"=>"BMW","carColor"=>"Grey", "carSpeed"=> "120 mph")
);
```

How can I combine the `"carColor"` of every `"carName"` in a single array so that I get:

```
$newObj = array
(
array("carName"=>"Volvo","carColor"=> array("Red", "Blue"), "carSpeed"=> "100 mph"),
array("carName"=>"BMW","carColor"=> array("White", "Grey"), "carSpeed"=> "120 mph")
);
```

Comment: If you tried anything please share ?

Comment: I kind of tried a for loop to store carName each time it changed but it didn't work at all, guess I'm not familiar enough to write this kind of code. Though it seems basic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name each array with the car name (not sure if that matters) you can do it this way

```
foreach($obj as $x=>$y){
$new[$y['carName']]['carName']=$y['carName'];
$new[$y['carName']]['carColor'][]=$y['carColor'];
$new[$y['carName']]['carSpeed']=$y['carSpeed'];
}
```

Comment: That did the job! Such a basic thing.

Comment: could this be modified to not insert doubles into the array?

Comment: Yes change $new[$y['carName']]['carColor'][]=$y['carColor']; to $new[$y['carName']]['carColor'][$y['carColor']]=$y['carColor'];