# get data from xml element with dynamic sub elements

Tags: php, xml

This is an example xml which i need to access its elements.
In this example, I need to perform a loop to add another -> to move to another element. I will get values from XML not generate an XML

```
<Person>
      <Address>
         <State>
            <Code>101</Code>
         </State>
      </Address>    
</Person>    
<Person>
      <Address>
         <State>
            <Code>101</Code>
         </State>
         <Phone> 123456789</Phone>
      </Address>   
</Person>
```

Code:

```
for($i=0; $i< count(Person); $i++)
{
  $element .= '->{<<element>>['.$i.']}';            
}

//output would something be like an element to get data from XML:        `
$person->{'Address'}->{'State'}->{'Code'};`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)

Comment: hi, im not trying to generate an XML, i am accessing its element dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

The `$item` in the loop is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) from which you can get the properies like `$item->Address->State->Code`

```
$data = <<<DATA
<Persons>
<Person>
      <Address>
         <State>
            <Code>101</Code>
         </State>
      </Address>    
</Person>    
<Person>
      <Address>
         <State>
            <Code>101</Code>
         </State>
         <Phone> 123456789</Phone>
      </Address>   
</Person>
</Persons>
DATA;

$items = simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->Address->State->Code;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/pW1bN)

If you want to use a for loop and a counter, you might use:

```
$items = simplexml_load_string($data);
$count = count($items->Person);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $items->Person[$i]->Address->State->Code;
}
```

Comment: For this one: 

`foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->Address->State->Code;
}`

is there a way like to mke it something like 

`$total_elements_inside_item= count($items);

for($i=0;$i<=$total_elements_inside_item $i++)
{
  $item->{element[0]}
then next loop wil be 
$item->{element[1]}->{element[2]}
}`

Comment: @djan I have added an update to my answer. But why not use the `foreach`?