# How to return XML return from curl in HTML?

Tags: php, html, xml, wordpress, curl

```
  <?php
$soapUrl = "http://10.65.28.221/Magic94Scripts/mgrqispi94.dll";

$xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:car="CarproPriceEstimation">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<car:EstimationDetails UserId="TEST" UserPassword="TEST">
  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
  <car:Price>
     <car:CDP></car:CDP>
     <car:OutBranch>'.$_SESSION["pickup-location"].'</car:OutBranch>
     <car:InBranch>'.$_SESSION["dropLocation"].'</car:InBranch>
     <car:OutDate>'.$_SESSION["pickupDate"].'</car:OutDate>
     <car:OutTime>'.$_SESSION["pickupTime"].'</car:OutTime>
     <car:InDate>'.$_SESSION["dropDate"].'</car:InDate>
     <car:InTime>'.$_SESSION["dropTime"].'</car:InTime>
     <car:CarGroup>'.$_SESSION["car-type"].'</car:CarGroup>
  </car:Price>
</car:EstimationDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: 3575E6F6964716D6964737545636962705F237375636F62705024727F607D694A336F646",
"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_post_string );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);

$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


// $xml= (array) simplexml_load_string($result);
// var_dump($xml);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

var_dump($array);

// 
// $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
// print_r($xml);


// // $json = json_encode($xml);

// // $ctarray = json_decode($json,TRUE);

// echo $ctarray;

?>
```

I am trying to get xml return data in my html by converting into array or anyway i have html on same page want to get some values from xml at different places of HTML. I have expected date of some car prices from API which i will show on the same page, i am not using ajax simply redirecting to page where curl will run and will display data on bottom of html page.

I am getting this XML on return when i echo result.

```
 <soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:body><estimationdetails>

<price>
 <debitorcode></debitorcode>
 <cdp></cdp>
 <vouchertype></vouchertype>
 <vouchercode></vouchercode>
 <cargroup>A</cargroup>
 <currency></currency>
 <outbranch>66</outbranch>
 <inbranch>66</inbranch>
 <outdate>01/03/2020</outdate>
 <outtime>06:30</outtime>
 <indate>01/04/2020</indate>
 <intime>02:30</intime>
 <status>Status : Confirmed</status>
 <cargroupprice cargroup="A">
  <rateno>0</rateno>
  <ratename></ratename>
  <solddays>31.00</solddays>
  <rentalsum>0.0000</rentalsum>
  <insurancesum>0.0000</insurancesum>
  <extrassum>0.0000</extrassum>
  <dropoffsum>0.0000</dropoffsum>
  <airportfee>0.0000</airportfee>
  <vatperc>5.00</vatperc>
  <vatamount>0.0000</vatamount>
  <totalamount>0.0000</totalamount>
  <alert></alert>
  <caravailable>Available</caravailable>
  <tariffcode>DEFAULT</tariffcode>
  </cargroupprice>
</price>

 <success>Y</success>

 </estimationdetails></soap-env:body></soap-env:envelope>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Did you check the logs for errors

Comment: array(0) { } i am getting this on return, i have seen error log it's empty.

Comment: Did you echo out the `$result` before you do anything with it? Do you check for cURL errors?

Comment: yes i echo $result it return XML i want from API but how i use it on my html. want to store it in array, maybe. 

Edit: this API is running by VPN client so it might will not work for you if you will test it on your end, Thanks

Comment: nobody can get to any ip address starting `10.` as theses are internal private network addresses :) Unless they are also inside your company network

Comment: Yes it's private network, i am using VPN client provided by API to send and return data, so far i am getting XML when echo but i am new with XML so no idea how can i use it inside my html.

Comment: So show us the XML you are getting, or at least a decent example

Comment: Sorry, i have updated question with return XML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205223/discussion-between-kamran-hassan-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: IS that all of it, because if it is its not valid XML

Comment: Yes that's all what makes it invalid cannot i use it on my html.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php