# how make node like this <node/> with php xmlwriter

Tags: php, xml

i need make a xml with php code, but i dont now how make a single node like `<node/>`
 using the xmlwriter method.
example

```
<node>
     <element>ONE</element>
     <element>TWO</element>
     **<node_i_want_but_idontnow/>**
     <element>end</element>
</node>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<node-name/>` is just an optimization. If an element node has no child nodes (elements, text, comments, ...). it can be closed directly. For the parser it is the same as `<node-name></node-name>`.

The serializer will apply that optimization by default. However if you add an empty string as content you will create a text child node and block the optimization:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('php://stdout');
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElement('node');

// element with content
$writer->writeElement('element', 'one');
// empty element
$writer->writeElement('another_element');
// element with empty child node
$writer->writeElement('another_element', '');

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node>
 <element>one</element>
 <another_element/>
 <another_element></another_element>
</node>
```