# Why is this PHP recursion function not working

Tags: php, recursion

I wrote a simple php function to walk over a multidimensional array and print its content in a preformatted way.
But the function doesn't go deep and only adds first-level leaf nodes to the text.

Can anyone please help to figure out the problem and the solution?

```
function LOP($arrayItself, $txt){
    foreach($arrayItself as $fieldName=>$fieldValue){       
            if(is_array($fieldValue)){
                    LOP($fieldValue, $txt);
            }
            else {
                    $txt .= "<$fieldName>  $fieldValue  </$fieldName>";
            }
    }
    return $txt;
```

}

Comment: Going out on a limb: since it appears you're trying to build an XML document here, I would recommend generating such a document using [a proper XML building library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php) instead of trying to stack up the elements yourself.

Answer (score 3):

In your `if(is_array($fieldValue))` block, you need to capture the return value of your recursive call to `LOP()`:

```
function LOP($arrayItself, $txt){
    foreach($arrayItself as $fieldName=>$fieldValue){       
            if(is_array($fieldValue)){
                    $txt = LOP($fieldValue, $txt);
            }
            else {
                    $txt .= "<$fieldName>  $fieldValue  </$fieldName>";
            }
    }
    return $txt;
}
```