# Error in parsing XML in PHP where I am doing wrong?

Tags: php

I am getting the following error while trying to render the following code in PHP

**"error on line 1 at column 37: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected"**

Can anyone of you tell me where I am doing wrong??

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'";
echo "<bookshop orderid='5'>";
echo "<buyer>Ali</buyer>";
echo "<deliverto>";
echo "<country>Pakistan</country>";
echo "<city>Islamabad</city>";
echo "<address>Sector 11</address>";
echo "</deliverto>";
echo "<item>";
echo "<booktitle>Fairy Tales</booktitle>";
echo "<quantity>1</quantity>";
echo "<price>1200</price>";
echo "</item>";
echo "</bookshop>";
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";`

Comment: Typo: `echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'";`... you should add the missing `?>` at the end of that line, as explained in the error, like this: `echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";`

Comment: btw you should make your xml with the inbuilt API's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php rolling your own is prone to break if you don't properly encode your values

Comment: Happy Christmas - why would  you do this? Why echo XML like this???

Comment: I was running a sample from the book.  I realized my mistake it was typo moreover, since header is already defined  there is absolutely no need to  re-define on line number 2.    Thanks to everyone who helped!